# How to cout a float/double with dynamic precision?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a = 3.14159;
    double b = 3.14159;
    cout.precision(6);
    cout << a << endl; //3.14159
    cout << b << endl; //3.14159
    cout.precision(10);
    cout << a << endl; //3.141590118
    cout << b << endl; //3.14159
    cout.precision(20);
    cout << a << endl; //3.141590118408203125
    cout << b << endl; //3.1415899999999998826
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain the difference between float and double?
How do we print float/double with dynamic precision?

Comment: Define "dynamic precision".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have your definition of dynamic correct something like this should work:

```
void print(float toPrint, int precision)
{
    cout.precision(precision);
    cout << toPrint <<endl;
}
```

cout.precision only changes the precision of the printing, it doesn't actually affect how precise the numbers are. If you print with more digits than your numbers have precision, you will get inaccurate digits.

Of course, cout.precision also only changes the maximum precision of the printing. To force it to print trailing zeros, do something like this:

```
void print(float toPrint, int precision)
{
    cout.precision(precision);
    cout << fixed;
    cout << toPrint <<endl;
}
```

The difference between a float and a double is that a double is approximately twice as precise as a float. In general, a float has something like 7 or 8 digits of precision, and a double has 15 or 16 digits of precision.

Comment: What happened of the fourth cout? It prints out 3.14159 after cout.precision(10). Why?

Comment: @Jiayi Simple, you told it to print with 10 digits of precision, so it rounded the 11th digit. This was a 9, so it rounded up, adding one to the previous digit making it a 10, adding one to the previous digit. Etc.

Comment: Then why doesn't it print 3.141590000 instead?

Comment: Cout will remove trailing zeroes unless you cout<<fixed; I'll add this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly you are wondering why both `float`s and `double`s lose precision after you adjust `cout.precision`.

This occurs because floating point numbers are stored in binary differently than normal whole numbers. A common example of why this matters is that the number `0.6` is stored in binary as `0011111100101...`. This, like `0.6666666...` in decimal, is an infinitely long number. Thus, your computer needs to decide at what point it should round/approximate the value. When you declare and initialize your floating point numbers `a` and `b`, the computer knows that it does not need to cram any value other than `3.14159` into the variable. However, when you then change `cout.precision`, the computer thinks it needs to round the floating point at a later location. Furthermore, `floats` are only 16 bits so it will almost always be less precise than the `double`, which is 32 bits. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) for their ranges.

Obviously to get the correct precision you shouldn't adjust `cout.precision` to be greater than the number of digits of your variable. However if you want to adjust the precision and just print out a bunch of zeroes after the end of your initial variable value, just use `cout << fixed << setprecision(number)`. See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a = 3.14159;
    double b = 3.14159;
    cout.precision(6);
    cout << a << endl; //3.14159
    cout << b << endl; //3.14159
    cout << fixed << setprecision(10);
    cout << a << endl; //3.141590118
    cout << b << endl; //3.141590000
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** [Another option is to use `limits`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/)

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense to have a "dynamic precision" where all digits different from `0` are displayed. That mode would have issues with fractional numbers that have infinite decimal digits, like the result of `1.0 / 3`.

The best you can do is to set the maximum precision you are willing to see with `precision`, just like in your example.